# Update detail view after deleting a record; UISplitViewController, UIStoryboard and CoreData

Tags: ipad, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm building an iPad app with a UISplitViewController, Story Boards, and Core Data. I have my Master and Detail views working such that I can add records and view each by touching the table in the Master view.

I have a button on my Detail view that deletes the record by doing a CoreData [context deleteObject:myObject]. This works - the Master table view updates and removes the currently selected row. However, I don't know what to do in the detail view. I need to somehow clear it back to the unselected (blank) state but I don't know how to go "back".

I get to the detail view through a segue from the Master table so I was thinking I needed to go "back" through that segue but I'm not clear on how to do that.

Thanks for any guidance,

Tom